# If I'm already running passenger standalone (for rails) on port 80, how might I also run an apache server (for drupal) on port 8080? Is this possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, port, passenger

Currently, when I visit the DNS which I'm wanting to point towards port 8080, Passenger Standalone "picks up" the port 8080 traffic and sends the browser to my rails site instead of sending me to the apache root I'm trying to get to.

However, when I go to examplesite.com:8080, I'm routed to the correct location.

So I guess my question is this, how do you handle situations like these where you want to run passenger standalone ***and*** apache?

There is a significant time investment I'd have to make to get my rails site up and running through apache, but I'm not entirely closed to just doing something like that.

Comment: Can you show us the command line you use to start passenger standalone?

Comment: (from app root) sudo passenger start -p 80 -e production